# Jsonix Get Only the Mapping , but not in a JS file that exports but probably in a json or a variable

Tags: node.js, npm, mapping, jsonix

i have gone through the documentation of jsonix available at

https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki

is there any way that we can generate the mapping as a json directly or in a variable and not as a file that we need to export and import/require in our application

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. Feel free to file a [feature request](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler/issues).